# What are internal and external osmotic pressures when referring to a cell?

Tags: biochemistry, cell-biology, membrane-transport, osmosis, intracellular-transport

I've seen the term used but cannot find a clear answer:
What are internal and external osmotic pressures when referring to a cell?

Answer (score 0):

The internal osmotic pressure is the osmotic pressure inside the cell. The external osmotic pressure is the osmotic pressure outside the cell. Osmotic pressure is proportional to the concentration of solutes.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Osmotic_pressure) has a perfectly reasonable page about this.